# Анимация клавиатуры на Android

Tags: android

Можно ли при клике на EditText, плавно выдвигать клавиатуру, а контент над эдит текстом поднимать над ним. Короче, выезд клавиатуры, как на айфоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, влиять на анимацию клавиатуры нельзя. Все из за того, что клавиатура - это такое же приложение. И вся анимация описана его разработчиками.
Поднимать контент можно.
Добавьте в манифест к активити ,на которую надо повлиять атрибут  `android:windowSoftInputMode` со значением `adjustResize` или `adjustPan` (я не помню, какой из них, попробуйте поочереди оба)

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

И можете начинать забывать о том, чтобы сделать что-либо "как на айфоне".
Андроид имеет свои, чаще всего более логичные гайдлайны и паттерны